# does dask compute store results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

Consider the following code

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {'data1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df_pd     = pd.DataFrame(data_dict) 
df_dask   = dd.from_pandas(df_pd,npartitions=2)

df_dask['data1x2'] = df_dask['data1'].apply(lambda x:2*x,meta=('data1x2','int64')).compute()

print('-'*80)
print(df_dask['data1x2'])
print('-'*80)
print(df_dask['data1x2'].compute())
print('-'*80)
```

What I can't figure out is: why is there a difference between the output of the first and second print? After all, I called compute when I applied the function and stored the result in df_dask['data1x2'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first print will only show the lazy version of the dask series, `df_dask["data1x2"]`:

```
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=2
0    int64
5      ...
9      ...
Name: data1x2, dtype: int64
Dask Name: getitem, 15 tasks
```

This shows the number of partitions, index values (if known), number of tasks needed to be done to get the final result, and some other information. At this stage, dask did not compute the actual series, so the values inside this dask array are not known. Calling `.compute` launches computation of the 15 tasks needed to get the actual values and that's what is printed the second time.

Comment: But in the line before the first print, I did call compute and store them in the dask dataframe. Are they not getting stored?

Comment: Oops, didn't spot that. They are stored, but the overal dataframe is still lazy.

Comment: Hmm. I can understand being lazy about computation (you don't compute until and unless a result is required), but here, there is no computation. Just storage of numbers computed by calling compute. What does it mean to be lazy in this context? What does it mean that the overall dataframe is still lazy?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but imagine someone came to you with a box of data. You can't see what's inside but you can ask to perform some computations and get the results. So you ask to retrieve `data1` column times 2 and say stored it in the box as `data2x`. Now this box is taken to someone else...

Comment: This is a really great answer. I added another though to help clarify that there is no such thing as dask.dataframe that is NOT lazy. Calling compute doesn’t create a non-lazy dask series - it creates a pandas series. Hence the difference!

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelDelgado your answer uses precise language!

Answer (score 2):

Dask does store results in memory on the workers or scheduler. But that’s not what’s driving the differences in displayed results. The two are displayed differently because they are different types of objects.

`df_dask['data1x2']` is a `dask.dataframe.Series`, which will only ever display a preview of the data structure and information about the number of tasks involved in calculating the values. Displaying any data requires at least moving data to the main thread, if not computation and possibly I/O, so dask will never do this unless explicitly asked to, e.g. with `df.head()`.

`df_dask['data1x2'].compute()` is a `pandas.Series`. It no longer has anything to do with dask and is by definition in-memory. Since all pandas data structures are in memory, the data is displayed by defualt.

When you call compute on a dask object it ceases to be a dask object. In this case, the first compute returns a pandas series. When you assign a pandas series to a dask data frame, dask partitions and sends the data to the workers, and then can no longer display the whole series. So you have to call compute again if you’d like to see the series displayed.

Imagine how useful this would be if your whole data frame were too large to fit into memory, e.g. if you had 1000 columns and 10m rows. This is what dask is designed for.